# Javascript onbeforeunload return value

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I finally found out what is causing one hell of an issue for me.

I am accessing and modifying the have javascript via vb.net, but i only need help with the javascript.

The document calls

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {return "ANNOYING TEXT" };
```

So lets so what can i modify the return value to so that it does not return anything.

Return false, null and 0 do not work.

I DO NOT HAVE ACCESS TO THE JAVASCRIPT.

Here is the callee:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload' ,function() {
      return 'Warning!\nIf you leave, you will cancel the installation of ' + 'SOME BULLSSHIT';
    });
```

I know i can not delete the function, i just need it to be disabled. or disable its parent callee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.onbeforeunload = null;`  to unbind using vanilla javascript

or `$(window).unbind('beforeunload');` using jQuery.

Comment: thats what i thought too when i fist came across this. doesn't work. Though it probably works in casual javascript. JQuery is off limits. but i dont mind you suggesting jquery its easy to translate.